# Rigid body delay, switching from animated to simulated?

Tags: animation, physics

This may be a limitation or bug. But keen for any ideas.

I'm simulating a falling block that gets hit and smashes mid flight. At the point of impact (with a sword), I've keyed the 'Animated' checkbox from on to off. It works, but there is a glitch at that frame, as the animated falling motion stops, and gravity starts accellerating the block again a frame later.

I've tried adding extrapolation to the curves just in case, and also animated without the sword impact and the glitch still occurs.

All of the block fragments are parented to an empty which is the object that's actually animated.

My understanding was that the bullet sim would continue with the objects' previous velocity and accelleration as it kicks in. Is this not correct?

Comment: try setting the physics frame rate to a multiple of the animation fps ( this is  possibly another bug in the simulation )

Comment: That does seem to help a little, but it still pauses pretty noticeably at the switching point rather than continuing it's velocity. Thx for reply.